# VirtualBox Guest Additions 6.0.10: modprobe vboxguest failed

Tags: linux, virtualbox, centos

I'm having "issue" while installing VirtualBox Guest Additions 6.0.10 on CentOS 8.

`[VBox_GAs_6.0.10]# ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`  will end up with following error

```
[VBox_GAs_6.0.10]# cat /var/log/vboxadd-setup.log
modprobe vboxguest failed
```

I've already installed following [see bellow] and re-run "./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" but still having issue.

```
[VBox_GAs_6.0.10]# yum install dkms binutils gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers 

[VBox_GAs_6.0.10]# yum install kernel-devel
```

Some more information

```
[VBox_GAs_6.0.10]# uname -r
4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64

[VBox_GAs_6.0.10]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3) (GCC)) #1 SMP Tue Jun 4 09:19:46 UTC 2019
```

Even I have installed kernel-headers by just enabling debug mode in bash for "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" it complains about following `VirtualBox Guest Additions: Kernel headers not found for target kernel 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64. Please install them and execute`.

And of course Package `kernel-headers-4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0.x86_64` is already installed.

Comment: Have you tried installing package kernel-**devel**-4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0.x86_64

Comment: Please don’t add comments to a question you have posted like this. Just edit your question to add the new information.

Comment: Good point  @wojtekM  but "Yes" Installed Packages: kernel-devel.x86_64, kernel-headers.x86_64 both on version 4.18.0-80.11.2.el8_0. I mentioned in those "yum" commands kernel-header first and then kernel-devel. Paradox is that VBoxLinuxAdditions.run script complains about "Kernel headers" but they are installed :(

Answer (score 1):

First, it's a good idea to always run `sudo yum update` prior to adding Guest Additions on a newly-installed machine.

Check the file `/var/log/vboxadd-setup.log`. In my case it pointed out that there was a missing dependency.  I needed `sudo yum install elfutils-libelf-devel`. (My installation included Development Tools, so your results may vary.)

After adding the missing dependency, I re-ran the GA autorun.sh and all was well.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to restart with `sudo reboot` after running `yum install dkms binutils gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers`.

This worked for me when facing the same error on Cent OS 8.